# Why SSL Certification appears differently when VPN is on/off?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, firewall, middleman

visiting gist.github.com[image: When VPN is off]
[image: When VPN is on]

Could it be virus or something in my computer locally, or it's some problems with my internet provider or even the government?

P.S yes, in China.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is probably some man-in-the-middle with the first certificate. But the attacks looks very dumb for me because it is using some "internet Widgits Pty Ltd" as the subject of the certificate instead of the expected hostname. Thus I doubt that the government is behind this man-in-the-middle attack.

You don't indicate if the attack occurs with or without VPN. If it is with VPN then I would not trust the VPN provider any longer.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The attack occurs when the VPN is off. That's why I wanted to ask where the attack might coming from. IMO if the attack is caused by something locally, it shouldn't go away as the VPN is turned on.

Comment: The attack might be anywhere in the network, i.e. in your local network, at the ISP etc. Depending on the kind of setup you are VPN (i.e. full VPN for all connections on this machine or only for the browser) it might even be local to your machine.

Comment: See http://news.softpedia.com/news/Dyre-Trojan-Uses-Its-Own-SSL-Certificate-to-Communicate-with-Control-Server-460224.shtml and http://www.securityweek.com/dyre-malware-takes-inventory-software-infected-systems . The MITM SSL certificate's name matches one that is used by a known banking trojan.

Comment: @AnandBhat: "Internet Widgits Pty Ltd" is the default name when you create a certificate with OpenSSL, so you will find it a lot.